Tensorflow.keras is not working, what should I do?
I installed Tensorflow on my computer but I cant get the line: "from tensorflow.keras import..." to work. I tried it on a different computer, I have tensorflow installed using pip: py -m pip install tensorflow
What Should I Do? I use windows and VSCode.

what do you mean "to work"? What happens, do you get error messages?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There may not be enough info here to answer this question.
But if you are using VSCode with the jupyter notebook plugins as your IDE, then VSCode allows you to switch between different python kernels, and so one likely possibility is that python kernel you installed tensorflow to is not the one that you're using to run the code.

I can assure you that I installed tensorflow because I was able to get the import and even write a program in it, however, I just cant get the "from tensorflow.keras import..." to work.
